# Searching for 2 keywords on same line in Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have these kind of codes and i want to search for the "WOW" & the chinese which is both contained on each line.

Sample code:

```
   Line: 1  <SENT>
   Line: 2     <VALUE Lang="WOW">skip</VALUE>
   Line: 3  </SENT>
   Line: 4  <SENT>
   Line: 5     <VALUE Lang="WOW">Mustang</VALUE>
   Line: 6  </SENT>
   Line: 7  <SENT>
   Line: 8     <VALUE Lang="WOW">超級跑車雷文頓</VALUE>
   Line: 9  </SENT>
   Line: 10 <SENT>
   Line: 11    <VALUE Lang="WOW">超級跑車雷文頓</VALUE>
   Line: 12 </SENT>
   Line: 13 <SENT>
   Line: 14    <VALUE Lang="WOW">skip</VALUE>
   Line: 15 </SENT>
   Line: 16 <SENT>
   Line: 17    <VALUE Lang="WOW">skip</VALUE>
   Line: 18 </SENT>
   Line: 19 <SENT>
   Line: 20    <VALUE Lang="WOW">skip</VALUE>
   Line: 21 </SENT>
```

Im using this code: `[^\x00-\x7F]+` and i was able to retrieve the chinese/non-english texts. However, this time, i only wanted retrieve the non-english texts if it has Lang="WOW" on the same line.

So for example, using the code above with 21 lines, i need to be able to find **Line: 8** & **Line 11**

Is it possible? Any clues and examples are greatly appreciated.

Comment: `(?<=Lang="WOW">)[^\x00-\x7F]+`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
Lang="WOW">\K[^\x00-\x7F]+
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/ZoqrvG/2).

**EXPLANATION**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Lang="WOW">              'Lang="WOW">'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \K                       discard text matched so far
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [^\x00-\x7F]+            any character except: '\x00' to '\x7F' (1
                           or more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
```